# Text is clipped when split between multiple divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The script in [**this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/D6L7u/296/) takes a long text and breaks it up in different divs. It does that by cloning the whole text in each div and incrementing the margin for each page so that only the required text is displayed. Like so:

```
for (var i = 2; i < page_no + 1; i++) {
    $("#stuff").append("<div id='page" + i + "' class='mydiv'></div>");
    var copy = $("#page1").clone().attr("id", "onecopy").css({
        "margin-top": '-' + (214 * (i - 1)) + 'px',
            "height": (214 * 2 * (i - 1)) + 'px'
    });

    $("#page" + (i)).append(copy);
}
```

The problem is that the text gets 'clipped' by the overflow/hidden property.

Is there a way so that the first line on a page is 'truncated' if clipped and that the last line is displayed fully if it is clipped?

Any workaround this most annoying of issues would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please add expected results to the demo. Not exactly clear what you are looking for

Comment: I would recommend tweaking your code so that instead of adding the same text into each div, just add a substring from that particular point in the text. Your current method is not very efficient and you don't have a lot of control over it.

Comment: Whichever method you choose though, you need to factor in the line spacing in the text. I think this is your main issue.

Comment: Nick, you are absolutely right. It is hugely inefficient and hacky to clone the text as I have done and play around with the margins. I am not entirely sure how I should proceed to split the text up into 'pages'... Have you any pointers, or have you seen this done before? If the text were simply words and spaces then we could characters I guess... the problem is that my final text will have skipped lines.

Comment: I've updated my answer to show a method of splitting the text between the divs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prevent the clipping by adding a `line-height` style, which is a factor of `mydiv`'s height.

To avoid problems with fractional point sizes, I've changed your code from 214px to 220px, and I set `line-height` as 22px:

```
.mydiv {
  width: 200px;
  height: 220px;
  border:solid 1px black;
  overflow:hidden;
  line-height: 22px;
}

$(function () {
  var page_no = Math.ceil($("#fullpage").height() / 220);

  for (var i = 2; i < page_no + 1; i++) {
    $("#stuff").append("<div id='page" + i + "' class='mydiv'></div>");

    var copy = $("#page1").clone().attr("id", "onecopy").css({
      "margin-top": '-' + (220 * (i - 1)) + 'px',
      "height": (220 * 2 * (i - 1)) + 'px'
    });

    $("#page" + (i)).append(copy);
  }
});
```

### Fiddle

---

**Update**

Your method of cloning the text and offsetting it by a top margin is clever, but it can lead to the clipping problems you experienced.  An alternative is to add only the text needed to each "page" `div`.

You can do so by adding the words one at a time until they overflow the `div`.  You can test for the overflow condition by comparing the div's `height` to its `scrollHeight`.

The code below accomplishes this:

```
function newPage() {
  pageNo++;
  return $('<div id="page'+pageNo+'" class="mydiv">')
            .appendTo('#stuff');
};

var words= $('#fullpage').text().split(' '),
    pageNo= 0,
    page= newPage(),
    i,
    len;

for(i = 0 ; i < words.length ; i++) {
  len= page.text().length;
  page.append(words[i]+' ');
  if(page[0].scrollHeight > page.height()) {
    page.html(page.text().substr(0,len));
    i--;
    page= newPage();
  }      
}
```

### Fiddle

Comment: Hello Rick, thank you so much for your update. Do you think this method is a vast improvement on the former in terms of speed of execution?

Comment: If speed is a concern, I would recommend rewriting in vanilla JavaScript.  If memory is a concern, my second method is better simply because it avoids duplicating the text content.  Neither method works if you have lines of different heights.  My second method fails altogether if you have embedded HTML, because it grabs text content only.  Embedded HTML makes this a much larger problem, which may deserve its own question.

Comment: That was going to be my next question :) I cannot believe there isn't a simpler way to split up a text (with embedded html) between different divs.. The end product in my case needs to output a PDF file. Nothing is working right now, this is a complete mess.